# Internet speed shared by multiple EC2 instances

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I am new to AWS. My task is to download large files from web and save in S3. I am using m4.xlarge to download and save with the downloading speed of ~11MB/s.

But when I launch multiple instances (m4.xlarge) and try to download files in parallel, downloading speed gets shared among the instances. For e.g., I am getting ~5.5MB/s each for 2 instances.

I thought, instances are independent of each other. Is there any configuration which I need to change, to get ~11MB/s in all the instances in parallel? Is there anything I am missing?

Comment: Lot of information missing. Are all instances in the same VPC? same subnet? public subnet or private subnet? How do they connect to the internet? NAT or internet gateway?

Comment: This sounds like a NAT instance to me... maybe running on an old t1 or m1 instance?  Unless of course 11 MB/s is all the bandwidth the remote site has available, assuming all the files are being downloaded from the same place.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The network bandwidth allocated to Amazon EC2 instances depend upon their **instance type**. Larger instances have higher bandwidth than smaller instances.

However, the network performance of one Amazon EC2 instance **will never impact the performance of another instance**. This is intentional so that there will not be a *noisy neighbour* problem between instances.

However, if different instances are downloading content from the *same website*, performance may be impacted due to **limited bandwidth to/from the remote site**. For example, the remote server might only serve 3 concurrent sessions. This might be what you are experiencing.

To take full advantage of bandwidth available on EC2 instances, upload/download files **in parallel** so that the network bandwidth is fully utilised.